# No output to service worker console with chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

[image]

I'm trying to build an extension to monitor the xhr portion of the devtools network tab.  I decided to start as simple as possible with the background script below. I'm seeing no errors on loading the extension, but don't see any output in the console.

[image]

manifest.json:

```
{
"manifest_version": 3,
"version": "1.0",
"name": "Hello World!",
"description": "Learning how to make a chrome extension!",
"icons": {
    "16": "images/puppy16.png",
    "48": "images/puppy48.png",
    "128": "images/puppy128.png"
},
"action": {
    "default_icon": "images/puppy.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
},
"background": {
    "service_worker": "background.js"
},
"host_permissions": [
    "https://cnn.com/*"
],
"permissions": [
    "webRequest"
]
}
```

In my background.js:

```
(function () {

    chrome.webRequest.onCompleted.addListener(
        function (details) {
            console.log('HELLO THERE!!!!', details);
        },
        { urls: ["<all_urls>"] }
    );

}());
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The code is correct but the URL is not. Right-click the address bar and choose `Always show full URLs`. It'll probably have `www` there, which means your host_permissions should be `https://www.cnn.com/` or better yet `*://*.cnn.com/`

Comment: Yes, that works! - Thank you. Would you like to enter it as the answer?